# Existence of polynomials under a determinant constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am having trouble with the following problem:

> Do there exist polynomials $a(x), b(x), c(y), d(y) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ for which the following holds?
>   $$
> \forall x, y \qquad 1+xy+x^2y^2 = a(x)d(y) - b(x)c(y)
> $$

I do not see how to approach this problem -- should I start making guesses for $a,b,c,d$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\, f(x,y) := 1 + xy + x^2y^2 .\,$ The function given by $\, g(x,y) := a(x)d(y)-b(x)c(y) \,$ has rank at most
 $\,2,\,$ **by definition**, which implies that the
 determinant of the
 $\,3\times 3\,$ matrix $\, \{g(x_i,y_j)\}_{i,j=1}^3 \,$ for **any** $\, x_i, y_j \,$
is $\,0.\,$ This is a direct
computation.

Let us call any function of two variables of the form $\, u(x)v(y) \,$ a **separable** or **rank** $1$ function.
Any linear combination 
$\, g(x,y) := \sum_{n=1}^r a_n\,u_n(x)v_n(y) \,$ of separable functions for any $\, u_n, v_n \,$ has rank **at most** $\,r.\,$ This is because the $\, n\times n\,$ matrix $\, \{g(x_i,y_j)\}_{i,j=1}^n \,$ for **any** $\, x_i, y_j \,$ has rank at most $\,r.\,$

In the case of $\,f(x,y),\,$ the determinant of the matrix 
 $\, \{f(i,j)\}_{i,j=1}^3 \,$ is $\,4.\,$ Therefore there **do not exist** functions $\, a,b,c,d \,$ such that 
$\, \forall x, y \qquad  f(x,y) = g(x,y). \,$ Note that 
$\, f(x,y) \,$ is the sum of $3$ separable functions and has rank exactly $3.$

Comment: Thanks, it is clear the idea but I do not understand how you proove that the matrix constructed with $g(I,j)$ has rank 2 (i.e. that is det is $0$). You just did the whole computation or there is something more I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: @clarkmaio I have added some more information.

Comment: After some research I get the definition of rank. Can you provide an article or an idea about how to proove statment you did about the rank of polynomials of the form $\sum_n u_n(x)v_n(y)$?